# How to apply Where condition on Children Table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have following SQL Query , due to some limitation because there are many more conditions in this query I have to convert this query to LINQ.

```sql
SELECT
    sh.BarCode
FROM
    Bars AS sh

    INNER JOIN BarDetail AS detail ON
        detail.BarCode = sh.BarCode
        AND
        detail.IsActive = 1

    INNER JOIN BarStatus AS st ON
        st.BarCode = sh.BarCode
        AND
        st.IsActive = 1
```

So I have done this so far at LINQ

```cs
var queryAble = _context.BarDetail
    .Include(x => x.Bar)
    .Include(x => x.Bar)
    .ThenInclude(y => y.BarStatus)
    .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
    .AsQueryable();
```

I want to apply condition on `barstatus` as well; condition is `barstatus` with `IsActive == true`. I am unable to do it .

I don't want to do it as raw SQL with `DbCommand`, I'd like to do it entirely using only Linq-to-Entities.

How would I do this maybe this way but its not working

```cs
var queryAble = _context.BarDetail
    .Include(x => x.Bar)
    .Include(x => x.Bar)
    .ThenInclude(y => y.BarStatus)
    .Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.Bar.BarStatus[SOMETHING HERE])
    .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: BTW, `.Where(x => x.IsActive == true)` can be changed to just `.Where(x => x.IsActive)` (assuming `IsActive` is `NOT NULL`).

Comment: Thankyou but in this case active is Nullable

Comment: "I don't want to do it in ADO Style, I want it to be in LINQ Style." - what do you mean by "ADO style" and "Linq style"?

Comment: Why is it nullable? That sounds like a bad DB design...

Comment: ADO Style means when we write SQL Within our C# Code

Comment: While T-SQL supports using arbitrary predicates in `JOIN` clauses, it isn't keeping with the spirit of SQL where predicates must always be in `WHERE` clauses and `JOIN` clauses must use _only_ tuple-equality.

Comment: Yeah its bad , I haven't designed db BTW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243175/discussion-between-wasim-and-dai).

Comment: No, because it's 1:14am where I am and I do what I feel like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is direct translation of your SQL to LINQ. Note that `Include` intorduced not for building query but for loading related data.

```cs
var query =
    from bar in _context.Bar
    from detail in bar.Details
    where detail.IsActive && bar.IsActive && bar.BarStatus.IsActive
    select bar.BarCode;
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer , actually I don't want to do it in this way. Its not good time wise . Is there any other way dealing it through the way I have mentioned above

Comment: @Wasim "actually I don't want to do it in this way. Its not good time wise " - why do you say that? If your queries are slow it means your DB needs the right `INDEX` objects and regularly maintained `STATISTICS` objects.

Comment: You are right but its too old to use why can't we go through LINQ , there would be a way around

Comment: @Wasim, be more concrete. Which result/class at the end do you expect. Note again   that `include` is not for building query filter, it is just instruction which related data is needed.

Comment: You are right for filtering  I have to add it in `WHERE` but because table is within table I am unable to filter on it.

Answer (score 1):

As I remarked in my comment, while your original SQL query *works*, it's best for `JOIN` clauses to use *only key (or tuple) equality*, while other predicates should be in the `WHERE` clause. Following that pattern shouldn't cause any changes to your runtime query execution plan, but I feel it's keeping with the relational-calculus that SQL is based on - and it also means you can instantly check if a `JOIN` is correct or not because you'll always be using *only* primary-key and foreign-key columns (which are presumably already indexed... *right?*).

So your query becomes:

```sql
SELECT
    b.BarCode
FROM
    Bars AS b
    INNER JOIN BarDetail AS d ON d.BarCode = b.BarCode
    INNER JOIN BarStatus AS s ON s.BarCode = b.BarCode
WHERE
    d.IsActive = 1
    AND
    s.IsActive = 1
```

...which is easier to translate into Linq-to-Entities:

Also:

- You don't need the `.AsQueryable()` call: all non-materialized queries created from `DbContext`'s `DbSet<T>` will be `IQueryable<T>` already.
- As you have navigation-properties you don't need to do a manual `Join`.

```cs
IQueryable<String> q = _context.BarCode
//  .Include( b => b.BarDetail )
//  .Include( b => b.BarStatus )
    .Where( b =>
        b.BarDetail.IsActive == true
        &&
        b.BarStatus.IsActive == true
    )
    .Select( b =>  b.BarCode );

List<String> list = await q.ToListAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

---

### Update: Without `b.BarDetail.IsActive == true`

> I can not directly add `Include( b => b.BarStatus )` because `BarStatus` doesn't have direct relationship with `BarCode`, its linked with `BarDetail`. So first we go into `BarDetail` and then after that we go in `BarStatus` using `BarDetail`

You can still do a manual `JOIN`:

```cs
IQueryable<String> q = _context.BarCode
//  .Include( b => b.BarDetail )
//  .Include( b => b.BarStatus )
    .Join( _context.BarStatus, s => s.BarCode, b => b.BarCode, ( s, b ) 
 => new { BarStatus = s, BarCode = b, BarDetail = b.BarDetail } )
    .Where( t =>
        t.BarDetail.IsActive == true
        &&
        t.BarStatus.IsActive == true
    )
    .Select( b => b.BarCode );

List<String> list = await q.ToListAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I can not directly add `Include( b => b.BarStatus )` because BarStatus does't have direct relationship with BarCode , its linked with BarDetail . So first we go into BarDetail and then after that we go in BarStatus using BarDetail

Comment: (A "relation" is not the same thing as a "relationship". A "relation" is a `TABLE` or `VIEW` object, whereas a "relationship" is a byword for a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint).  You can make `.Include( b => b.BarStatus )` work by defining _artificial_ navigation properties in your entity classes and in your `OnModelCreating` method, even if they don't exist in your actual database (just be careful if you're using EF Migrations: you won't want it to actually create the FK constraint in the actual database, though as you have a DB-first system I assume you have EF Migrations disabled?)